# Adding an empty PostGIS table as a layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.2 (and 3.0), when trying to load a PostGIS layer into QGIS using a Python function as follows:

```
def create_pg_layer(table,schema,geom_column='geom'):
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
    # set host name, port, database name, username and password
    uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432","","","")
    uri.setDataSource(schema, table, geom_column)
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), table, "postgres")
    return vlayer
```

It returns a `None` layer object, and fails to load the layer when the PostGIS `table` is empty, but succeed when the `table` contains a non-zero number of rows with non-empty geometry.

This is annoying because a PostGIS table can be treated as invalid (or valid) depending on its content.

Is there a way to allow an empty PostGIS table to be loaded into QGIS in above?

Comment: Does your empty table still have a corresponding row in geometry_columns?

Comment: @user30184, yes, the empty table does show up in  `public.geometry_columns`

Comment: What if table contains one row but with empty geometry?

Comment: I have a feeling that QGIS wants to know the spatial extents of the layer and therefore fails when the table is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say what goes wrong for you but this code adds an empty table into map project without any errors for me when I run it from the Python console:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
# set host name, port, database name, username and password
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "mydb", "user", "passwd")
# set database schema, table name, geometry column and optionally
# subset (WHERE clause)
uri.setDataSource("public", "empty", "wkb_geometry", "")

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "empty_from_pg", "postgres")   
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Attributes appear correctly and layer-properties show correct CRS and geometry type:

```
Encoding UTF-8
Geometry Polygon (Polygon)
CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
Extent Empty
Unit degrees
```